# Calling Nasm function from C but return -nan

Tags: c, assembly, return, nasm, nan

I'm learning assembly and how to call nasm function from C.
So i wrote a simple code just to try it:

This is my test.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int test(int c);

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int x = 10;
    printf("Original value: %d\nUpdated value: %d\n",x,test(x));
    return 0;

}
```

This is my test.nasm file:

```
; 32 bit

SECTION .text

global test ;unix
global _test ;windows

test:
_test:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push ebx

    mov ebx , [ebp+8]
    mov eax, ebx
    sub eax, 2

    pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

As expected i get:

```
Original value: 10
Updated value: 8
```

But if i change test.c file as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern float test(float c);

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    float x = 10.0;
    printf("Original value: %f\nUpdated value: %f\n",x,test(x));
    return 0;

}
```

The output is:

```
Original value: 10.000000
Updated value: -nan
```

Could, please, someone explain why i get this and how should i correct it?
Thanks in advance.

---

Edit:

Thanks all for answers. I've edited the nasm file for the floating variables:

```
; 32 bit

SECTION .data
align 16
y:  dd  2.0 , 2.0, 2.0, 2.0

SECTION .bss
alignb 16
A:  resd    4

SECTION .text

global test ;unix
global _test ;windows

test:
_test:
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    push ebx    

    movss xmm0 , [ebp+8]
    subps xmm0, [y]
    movaps [A], xmm0
    fld dword[A]        

    pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Now it works as expected. Is that code correct?

Comment: I take it you didn't modify your assembler code to use floating point instructions?

Comment: As suggested by @FredLarson, if you've got a `test` function that operates on floats, then please include that code in your question as well. If you don't have such a function the answer is simple: your `test` function accepts and processes _integers_; you'll have to rewrite it if you want it to accept and process floats.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The test file is the same for both version of the C one. thought I should change nasm file too, but I don't know how to modify it. Thought was fine since are just scalar not 64 bit ..

Comment: Simple trick: Write the function in C, compile it, and study the resulting machine code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

machine code generated by C compilers generally follows a [specific calling protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), depending on the function signature. For instance, on the X86-64 platform, functions will see their parameters placed in certain registers, depending on their types and numbers: integral types (int, long, char, etc.) will be placed in generic registers (`RAX`, `RDX`, `RCX`, etc), while floating point values will be passed in XMM registers. Likewise, values may be returned differently depending on the function return type.

In your case, you are targeting the IA-32 platform: the convention there is to return integral values through the x86 `EAX` register, and floating point values through the x87 `ST0` register (parameters are still passed through the stack).

So, by changing the function signature, you are telling the compiler that `test` will no longer return its value the same way, and since your assembly code doesn't touch the floating point registers, you get as a result whatever was stored in there. Furthermore, subtracting the integer encoded value `2` to the 32bit floating point encoded value `10.0` (which turns out to be `$41200000`) will probably not yield what you would expect.

Comment: Also, functions and parameters declared as `float` always actually use `double`.  This is a C feature since the 1970s.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. I did not know it was necessary to return the floating-point values ​​in the registers ST0. The link explains well the calling protocol. 
I edited the file nasm and I managed to make it work; could you kindly give it a try?

Comment: I actually didn't try your code, I just answered it from the top of my head (and some calculation for the fp value). If you got it working, then it's all good!